# How to receive Intent. ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED Intent. ACTION_PACKAGE_REMOVED in appwidget?

Tags: android, android-intent, widget

How to receive `Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED` and `Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_REMOVED` in appwidget?

I've tried to add intent-filter in Manifest:

```
 <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <!-- The widget provider -->
        <receiver android:name=".NetsWidgetProvider">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED"/>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED"/>
                <action android:name="com.oozic.widget.incstage.nets.ACTION_NOT_INSTALL"/>
                <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />

            </intent-filter>
            <!-- This specifies the widget provider info -->
            <meta-data android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
                    android:resource="@xml/widgetinfo" />
        </receiver>

    </application>
```

and I also tried register in Code:

```
@Override
   public void onEnabled(Context context) {

      registerReceiver(context);
      Utils.log(TAG, "Register PACKAGE_ADDED PACKAGE_REMOVED");

   }

   private void registerReceiver(Context context) {
       IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
       filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED);
       filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_REMOVED);
       context.getApplicationContext().registerReceiver(this, filter);

   }
```

But both didn't work. 
Thanks!

Comment: Did you try to get the call when your own package is added or removed? Because that doesn't work: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED

Comment: Hi Time, What is the meaning of "Note that the newly installed package does not receive this broadcast."? How long can be counted as "NEWLY"?

Comment: Eh sorry for this unclear definition. With newly installed package I meant the package that contains this code. If you install YOUR package with this code, it won't be notified about it, neither when you remove it.

Comment: Thanks. I am not under this situation. I wanna receive message in another widget which show some apk's status.

Comment: Could you try adding `<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />` to the intent filter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I send a broadcast to my widget, in my custom launcher when it get the PACKAGE_REMOVED/ADDED message. This is the only work around I found to fix this.

Comment: Actually you can use the intent in the manifest. You just need to handle onReceive instead of onUpdate.

Answer (score 8):

In AndroidManifest.xml adding `<data android:scheme="package" />` solved the issue.

```
<receiver android:name=".PackageAddedReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED"/>
        <data android:scheme="package" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
    <receiver android:name=".NetsWidgetProvider"
        android:label="@string/appwidget_name" android:icon="@drawable/icon">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
            <action android:name="com.oozic.widget.incstage.nets.ACTION_NOT_INSTALL"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_DATA_CLEARED"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED"/>
            <data android:scheme="package" />
        </intent-filter>
        <!-- This specifies the widget provider info -->
        <meta-data android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
                android:resource="@xml/appwidgetinfo" />
    </receiver>
```

Comment: As an addition to this anwer, the key here is "android:scheme" which was missing from OP's original manifest. In Java you could set the scheme like so:
filter.addDataScheme("package");